# Pyinstaller - Bundle excel file to onefile exe

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, pyinstaller

I've created an EXE file using pyinstaller which includes excel file. see the following code:

```
import pandas
from tkinter import *
    
sec = pandas.read_csv("sectionsize.csv")
    
win = Tk()
win.title('Imp vs Metric Section size')
win.geometry('320x100')
win.attributes("-topmost", True)
win.resizable(0,0)

def reset(dummy=None):
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e2.delete(0, 'end')
    
def conv(dummy=None):
    s1 = str(e1.get())
    s2 = str(e2.get())
    a = s1.upper()
    b = s2.upper()
    
    if len(a)!=0 and len(b)==0:
        try:
            imp_index = sec[sec['Imperial']==a].index[0]
            x = sec['Metric'][imp_index]
            e2.delete(0, 'end')
            e2.insert(END, x)
        except:
            x = 'Check Section size'
            e2.delete(0, 'end')
            e2.insert(END, x)
    
    elif len(a)==0 and len(b)!=0:
        try:
            metric_index = sec[sec['Metric']==b].index[0]
            y = sec['Imperial'][metric_index]
            e1.delete(0, 'end')
            e1.insert(END, y)
        except:
            y = 'Check Section size'
            e1.delete(0, 'end')
            e1.insert(END, y)
            
    elif len(a)!=0 and len(b)!=0:
        e1.delete(0, 'end')
        e2.delete(0, 'end')
    else:
        pass

win.bind('<Return>', conv)
win.bind('<Escape>', reset)

l1=Label(win, text='Imperial')
l1.place(x=25, y=10)

l2=Label(win, text='Metric')
l2.place(x=25, y=50)

e1=Entry(win, width=30)
e1.place(x=90, y=10)
e1.focus_set()

e2=Entry(win, width=30)
e2.place(x=90, y=50)
  
win.mainloop()
```

The exe file opens and works perfectly on my computer. The only problem is this file requires the excel file to be in the same folder. How can I get the excel file bundled into the EXE without requiring an external file? Any input will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to use the `--add-data` flag

From the docs of Pyinstaller:

> What to bundle, where to search:
> --add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
> Additional non-binary files or folders to be added >to
> the executable. The path separator is platform
> specific, `os.pathsep` (which is `;` on >Windows
> and `:` on most unix systems) is used. This >option
> can be used multiple times.